# sharepoint next url give repeat data again

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, paging

I am using sharepoint REST api. i have query like below:

```
https://<SITEURL>/_api/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?$select=ID,StartDate,Modified,DueDate,Body,Status,Assigned/ID,Assigned/Title&$expand=Assigned&$filter=(Status+ne+%27Completed%27)&$orderby=StartDate+desc&$top=20
```

so i get nexturl in response like below :

```
https://<SITEURL>/_api/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_StartDate%3d20180506%252018%253a30%253a00%26p_ID%3d1426&%24select=ID%2cStartDate%2cModified%2cDueDate%2cBody%2cStatus%2cAssigned%2fID%2cAssigned%2fTitle&%24expand=Assigned&%24filter=(Status+ne+%27Completed%27)&%24orderby=StartDate+desc&%24top=20
```

But its give some already given data as well it also skip some data also.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It might be happening because of the encoding. Try to replace '%24' in the nexurl with '$' symbol.

Comment: @VishnuS i was tried still not get data some data skipped and give repeated data

Comment: Can you try API call with decoded url. Like, `decodeURIComponent(nexturl)` .

Comment: @VishnuS if i decode that url then it will not give next data its just return same data.

Comment: Can you try this url in your browser, `https://<SITEURL>/_api/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_StartDate%3d20180506%252018%253a30%253a00%26p_ID%3d1426&$select=ID%2cStartDate%2cModified%2cDueDate%2cBody%2cStatus%2cAssigned%2fID%2cAssigned%2fTitle&%24expand=Assigned&%24filter=(Status+ne+%27Completed%27)&%24orderby=StartDate+desc&$top=20`

Comment: @VishnuS what you had changed in url??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78226/discussion-between-vishnu-s-and-vishal-thakkar).